# Running code before a BCL call with AOP in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, aop, postsharp, afterthought

I'm trying to call a function after/before every function call to BCL in an ASP.NET application.

For example when `Server.MapPath` is called I want to call my own function right after and before that particular call.

Is there an AOP library that supports this? Can PostSharp or Afterthought do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried weaving the original assembly from the GAC and storing the result an local copy in your binary directory? 
that *should* work.
however:
You may need to define your own method on how to define a pointcut definition.
i think both, postsharp and afterthought support assembly wide pointcut definitions,
but doing that would mean that you define it *within* the assembly.
I have seen someone managing to do this with postsharp, but could not find it anymore :/ 
I hope i can give you a better answer when i dived more into Afterthought. I am currently porting a project from Postsharp to Afterthought - what makes me quite unhappy...